# Validate Hive Query from a Java Service

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I want to validate a Hive query through a Java service class. If a table isn't there in hive, then it should return some status that it is incorrect. For example, if the query is "select * from example_table;", then after validation this should return some kind of an error message. And if the query is "select * from real_table where name='abc';", then this should return OK or something like that.

I am currently able to query using `ProcessBuilder` and process the stream:

```
    ProcessBuilder hiveProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("hive", "-e",
            "select * from real_table where name='abc'");
    Process hiveProcess = hiveProcessBuilder.start();
    // other logics
```

My current problem is if this "real_table" query is valid then it triggers a map-reduce job and then returns the result and then I can process the stream and figure out whether it is valid or not.  This whole process is a time consuming one. Does hive provide some method to validate the query without triggering map-reduce job.

Comment: Perhaps you can prepend "explain" to your SQL statement, like `explain select * from some_table where...` and submit it. You'll get back a non-zero return code if anything in your statement is incorrect (table name, expressions, syntax etc). If the error status is > 0, you can then capture error message to get more details.

Comment: @mazaneicha  Thank you for the answer. Explain query really works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you :)